# Creating a dynamic one page web application

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, web-applications

I would like to make a web application (PHP) that will have overlay container that contain dynamic fields/forms.

I would like the user to complete the form but not be taken away from the main part of the page.

Imagine, browsing a website and reporting a page error into an overlay but not being taken away from the page you were reading.

Also, is it possible to make the form multiple parts/pages, such as user clicks next button and the next part of the form is presented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice example of this type of web app here, with some useful tips:

- [The Future of Web Apps - Single Page Applications](http://happyworm.com/blog/2010/08/23/the-future-of-web-apps-single-page-applications/)

Comment: The linked page is simply excellent!

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could easily create the kind of form you want where the whole page is **not** reloaded upon submission.

Going into more details, check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/). There a set of usually very simple to implement power tools to help create a dynamic webpage.

So jQuery UI stuff for layout (look at tabs) and ajax through jQuery for your communication with the server (PHP).

Comment: no, ajax != single page application. SPA requires a framework (or many frameworks) to handle client side routing, data modeling, etc.

Comment: @Tim I was answering his question about a form that submits without reloading the page. Not what I would recommend to have a full blown single page web app.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished building a single-page application using the Yii Framework for PHP and Jquery (Jquery UI as well).

What I have learned is that Jquery isn't adequate enough to handle a true single-page application.

What you need to use is a library that handles a lot of issues that will come up whilst building SPA's and frees you from having to do a lot of DOM based manipulations.

Instead what you'd end up doing is actually write a true application and let the 'library' handle those aspects for you.

One library that comes to mind is AngularJS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: link in answer returns 404. Could you update the link?